# Oracle Export with SQL Developer and "Special chars"

Tags: oracle

Sorry for this "stupid" Questions but iam not able to find a solution..

I have an Table in my Oracle Database. The "ä,ö,ß" are stored in this Format:

\344
\374

Is there anyway to convert them back? I need an excel sheet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really mean is that the tool you used to get this data *renders* the characters as \344 \374.

To make sure how they are stored you would actually need to request a dump. As in

```
alter system dump datafile xx block min y block max z ;
```

This is the best test.  It might well as well be that your chars are stored OK but your tooling settings are wrong. To find out you first need to know the database character set

```
 select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

And then compare 344 374 with the expected codes.  As a matter of fact 344 is the correct octal value for a umlaut with the ISO 8859-1 character set.

Make sure your client NLS_LANG settings (either environment variable or registry setting) is well set (e.g. for windows WE8MSWIN 1252)

Comment: That's still OK because a umlaut is still equal to 344 octal in UTF8. Please tell us what tool you are using to display these codes (sqlplus ?, toad, java based, odp.net ?) and on what platform ? Mac, Windows, Unix ?

Comment: SQLdeveloper does not use NLS_LANG because it's a Java tool and therefore it does not use the OCI dll (it normally uses the JDBC thin driver).  So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The field where these characters are stores is of type varchar2 ? Right ?

Comment: SQLdeveloper has a setting in Tools => Preferences => Environment => Encoding. The default is UTF8. DO you also have this enabled ? Otherwise, just try to do a select in sqlplus in a windows command window with NLS_LANG set to GERMAN_GERMANY.WE8MSWIN1252 to see if the pb is rendering or storing.

Comment: fixed it with search & replace. But thanks a lot for the informations!